# Finding the term that is independent of $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the term that is independent of $x$ in the expansion of
>
> **(i)** $\quad \left(x-\frac{2}{x}\right)^6$
>
> **(ii)** $\quad \left(2+\frac{3}{x^2}\right)\left(x-\frac{2}{x}\right)^6$

This is what I have attempted to do, I know how to do the first question:

i) $^6C_3\times(-2)^3$

Therefore, the term independent is equal to $-140$.

ii) But how would I do this with the second step?

Thank you!

Comment: Hint: split the product into 2 parts with factors $2$, $\frac{3}{x^2}$ respectively, find the independent term in each, then add them up. The first one would be twice what you found at the previous step. For the second one, find the term in $x^2$ in the binomial expansion, then multiply it by $\frac{3}{x^2}$.

Comment: $^6C_3\times(-2)^3=-160$

Comment: $\left(2+\frac{3}{x^2}\right)\left(x-\frac{2}{x}\right)^6=2\left(x-\frac{2}{x}\right)^6+\frac{3}{x^2}\left(x-\frac{2}{x}\right)^6$

Comment: How do you do the first question? Why $^6C_3\times(-2)^3$?

Answer (score 1):

By the Binomial Theorem,
\begin{align*}
\left(x - \frac{2}{x}\right)^6 & = \sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}x^k\left(-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{6 - k}\\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k} x^k(x^{-1})^{6 - k}(-2)^{6 - k}\\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k} x^kx^{k - 6}(-2)^{6 - k}\\
& = \sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k} x^{2k - 6}(-2)^{6 - k}
\end{align*}
The constant term is obtained when $2k - 6 = 0$, which, as you determined, occurs when $k = 3$.  The corresponding term of the binomial expansion is 
$$\binom{6}{3}x^{2 \cdot 3 - 6}(-2)^3 = \binom{6}{3}(-2)^3 = 20 \cdot (-8) = -160$$
You made an arithmetic error in the final step.

For the second problem, distribute to obtain
\begin{align*}
\left(2 + \frac{3}{x^2}\right)\left(x - \frac{2}{x}\right)^6 & = \left(2 + \frac{3}{x^2}\right)\sum_{k = 0}^6 \binom{6}{k}x^k\left(-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{6 - k}\\
& = 2\sum_{k = 0}^6 \binom{6}{k}x^k\left(-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{6 - k} + \frac{3}{x^2}\sum_{k = 0}^6 \binom{6}{k}x^k\left(-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{6 - k}\\
& = 2\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}x^{k}\left(-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{6 - k} + 3\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}x^{k - 2}\left(-\frac{2}{x}\right)^{6 - k}\\
& = 2\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}x^{k}(x^{-1})^{6 - k}(-2)^{6 - k} + 3\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}x^{k - 2}(x^{-1})^{6 - k}(-2)^{6 - k}\\
& = 2\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}x^{k}x^{k - 6}(-2)^{6 - k} + 3\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}x^{k - 2}x^{k - 6}(-2)^{6 - k}\\
& = 2\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}x^{2k - 6}(-2)^{6 - k} + 3\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \binom{6}{k}x^{2k - 8}(-2)^{6 - k}
\end{align*}
The constant term in the first summation occurs when $2k - 6 = 0 \implies k = 3$.  The constant term in the second summation occurs when $2k - 8 = 0 \implies k = 4$.  Hence, the constant term is 
\begin{align*}
2\binom{6}{3}x^{2 \cdot 3 - 6}(-2)^{6 - 3} + 3\binom{6}{4}x^{2 \cdot 4 - 8}(-2)^2 & = 2\binom{6}{3}(-2)^3 + 3\binom{6}{4}(-2)^2\\
& = 2 \cdot 20 \cdot (-8) + 3 \cdot 15 \cdot 4\\
& = -320 + 180\\
& = -140
\end{align*}

Comment: Too much work to find only one coefficient.